# OpenCV: Single face detection

Tags: python, opencv

Would like to know how can I limit the for loop to work only with the first face, that is faces[0]

```
#faces here is rectangular co-ordinates. Example
#[((113, 18, 394, 358), 33)] for a single face
    if faces:
         for i in faces:
         #Detection Code here
```

Comment: What is the type of `faces`? I haven't worked with OpenCV, but wouldn't `i = faces[0]` work?

Comment: I'm gonna reply with a full answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
i = faces[0]
```

That way you shouldn't have to modify any code after it.